# Crawling SSL site with scrapy

Tags: python, ssl, scrapy

I've to crawl https://dms.psc.sc.gov/Web/dockets which uses TLS v1.2 using scrapy framework. But in requesting the URL it fails to load and raise `[<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'OpenSSL.SSL.Error'>>]`.

There is issue discussed on git https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/981 but it did not work for me. I have scrapy v 0.24.5 and twisted version >=14.

When I try to crawl another site which also uses TLS v1.2 it works but not for the https://dms.psc.sc.gov.
How to solve this issue?

Comment: No way to get more SSL error details than that?

Comment: I see curl also fails with this site ```$ curl -v https://dms.psc.sc.gov/Web
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
```

Comment: same for python requests, they also fail with ```SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

Comment: @AlexK. yes did not find any details about that error other than the issues on git. Even implementing customContextFactory did not solved the problem.

Comment: Looks like a broken cert chain: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=dms.psc.sc.gov&latest so perhaps look for scrapy options to ignore thses types of probs

Answer (score 5):

[PR fixing this problem](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/1101) in Scrapy was already merged. Recently (in February 2016) there was another pull request fixing [similar bug](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/1815)

I see with most recent Scrapy version I can fetch your page all right, but with older versions problem still appears.

In general, if you stumble on HTTP-s problem with Scrapy the solution is:

- upgrade Scrapy to newest version
- check what version of Twisted you use, if it's not most recent update to most recent Twisted version (as of time of writing versions above 14 are confirmed to be significantly better when it comes to SSL)

If you still experience problems after updating Scrapy and Twisted you may need to subclass ScrapyClientContextFactory - see answer below for details.

More details in [this github issue](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1435)

Comment: Upgrading the Scrapy to 1.0 and twisted resolved my problem.

Comment: I still have this problem on version 1.0.5

Comment: @OleHenrikSkogstrøm yeah, since my original answer another problems came up, fixes were merged two weeks ago, and are available in version 1.1 can you try with that? Also which Twisted version you use? I edited my post to add note about updating Twisted, it is important to use version above 14.

Comment: @PawelMiech, thank you for getting back to me I tried to upgrade to Scrapy 1.1rc1 and rc 3 they both gave me the same error :-/ I checked twisted and i had the lates version installed. Tried downgrade twisted too, no change. Is there a previous version of Scrapy that might work? I on osx 10.11.3 (El capitan). Using Python 2.7.3

Comment: @OleHenrikSkogstrøm maybe you could open new question for that? It would be good to note which domain you're crawling and add all details that you shared here (specify versions of twisted and Scrapy). I see you have somewhat old Python version but I'm not sure if it matters here.

Answer (score 3):

1.**add**`DOWNLOADER_CLIENTCONTEXTFACTORY='testproject.CustomContext.CustomClientContextFactory'`
    to your *settings.py*

2.**create file** called *CustomContext.py* in your project directory
        and add the below code

```
from OpenSSL import SSL
from twisted.internet.ssl import ClientContextFactory
from twisted.internet._sslverify import ClientTLSOptions
from scrapy.core.downloader.contextfactory import ScrapyClientContextFactory
class CustomClientContextFactory(ScrapyClientContextFactory):

    def getContext(self, hostname=None, port=None):
        ctx = ClientContextFactory.getContext(self)
        # Enable all workarounds to SSL bugs as documented by
        # http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_options.html
        ctx.set_options(SSL.OP_ALL)
        if hostname:
            ClientTLSOptions(hostname, ctx)
        return ctx
```

**Note:** It worked well for crawling with **https** sites in windows but when I tried the same in Ubuntu 14.04 it throws error as below :-

```
from twisted.internet._sslverify import ClientTLSOptions
exceptions.ImportError: cannot import name ClientTLSOptions
```

It would be great if anyone adds solution for the above error.

**EDIT:**

instead of using `from twisted.internet._sslverify import ClientTLSOptions`

I have changed it to the below

```
try:
    # available since twisted 14.0
    from twisted.internet._sslverify import ClientTLSOptions
except ImportError:
    ClientTLSOptions = None
```

Comment: Upgrading the Scrapy to 1.0 and twisted resolved my problem.

Comment: @HassanRaza I was already having 1.0.1 version and It started working when I followed the the steps what I have mentioned under EDIT part in my answer

Comment: TypeError: unbound method getContext() must be called with ClientContextFactory instance as first argument (got CustomClientContextFactory instance instead)

Comment: This is working well for us, but if we also add proxying middleware, this fix does NOT work. Does anyone know how to use this solution with proxying, too?

Answer (score 0):

Anyone having "TypeError: unbound method getContext() must be called with ClientContextFactory instance as first argument ..."

Replace `ctx = ClientContextFactory.getContext(self)`

with  `ctx = ScrapyClientContextFactory.getContext(self)`

Answer (score 0):

Vinodh Velumayil' answer is right. But I had to edit this string:

```
ctx = ClientContextFactory.getContext(self)
```

to this:

```
inst = ClientContextFactory()
ctx = inst.getContext()
```

Comment: Please consider writing this as a comment on his answer.

Comment: If my reputation was more than 50, I would do so.